# Finding a pole of inaccessibility relative to multiple points without using rasters

Tags: qgis, geometry, proximity

I want to find a 'point of inaccessibility' from a series of points, representing towns and villages in Scotland. Using FOSS GIS tools (QGIS, SAGA, GRASS, Postgres/PostGIS ... ).

This is the point furthest from any centre of population. This would be the centre of the largest circle which doesn't contain a town, but it will have a town on its edge.

There's a raster approach, which works - the GDAL **Proximity** filter.

> Is there a *VECTOR* based way to do this? One that doesn't require rasterisation?

Here's my attempt with rasters...

- Start with a point layer in a suitable projection in meters (I'm using OSGB, 27700)
- Add a field called "one", and set to integer with constant value 1.
- Vector to raster , editing command to use **-a one** and using GEO rather than pixel. Make sure pixels are square!
- Create contours on the proximity raster (in this case, 1 km wide)

Here's what it looks like. I drew some candidate points by hand  ;-)

[image]

I thought that dissolving repeated buffers (using the **Multi ring buffer** plugin) might work, but I suspect I don't have enough memory for this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is the centre of triangle excircle with largest radius, that touches no more than 3 points. In the picture below first 11 such centeres shown. They are labelled by their ranking number.

[image]

It is enough to weed out ones that are outside triangles and define the champion, i.e. No3 in the picture.

UPDATE INSPIRED BY STEVEN FINDING:

[image]

Result above unlike first solution obtained in ArcGIS without scripting (but with advanced license) and it works! However it can produce questionable results on the edges of a study area, e.g. point No 1, i.e. second remotest point found...

Comment: Wow, thanks sharing this! I tried to follow your workflow in QGIS by (1) Points to Delaunay (`Vector | Delaunay Triangulation`), (2) Select champion triangle (Calculated `$area` on the attribute table of Delaunay polygons) and saved the largest one as a new layer (3) Find circumcenter (`Processing | GRASS | Vector | v.voronoi.skeleton` on the champion triangle). Do you think this method is correct?

Comment: First step is correct. I computed exradius centres for ALL triangles. To find centre I constructed inward perpendicular for midpoints of all 3 sides and find intersection ( combination 3,2).

Comment: Circumscribed circle of triangle, not excircle.

Comment: Thanks so much! (and thanks for nice picture, too. The more I lean the background about it, the more it becomes fascinating.)

Comment: Thank you for this! I noticed that the candidate points (from the raster approach) all seem to be at tripoints on the voronoi mesh. This looks like a promising approach. I suspect I need to do a bit more reading on the relationship between Voronoi and Delauney :)

Comment: Nice observation! I'll test it and update the answer. Unlike first solution, it will require no scripting at least in Arcgis.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a follow-up. Thanks to @FelixIP for pointing me in the right direction!

Using the OSM data from Australia, I was able to find the "point of inaccessibility" on the Australian Mainland - I make it around 260km equidistant from Akarnenehe, Bedourie, and Mount Dare, at  POINT(137.234888 -24.966466)

[image]

I found a fairly easy workflow in QGIS which uses a combination of the raster and vector approaches. I'm sure a similar approach would work in other GISes.

The 'a-ha' moment came from noticing this

> The maxima all fall on tri-points on the voronoi mesh - points where adjacent triplets of voronoi polygons meet.

The approach was as follows :-

- work in a meter-based projection. I used 3857, not ideal but my OSM data was in that format :)
- get a layer representing points of interest **place in ('city','village','town','hamlet')**
- create a **voronoi mesh** from this layer
- use **extract nodes** to get the tripoints
- create the proximity raster (as shown in the question)
- clip the raster to the outline of the landscape, so sea pixels are set to 0.
- use **Point Sampling tool** on the extracted nodes against the raster

Then use **Db Manager** and **Virtual Layers** to find the node with the largest distance value on the raster.

```
select 
    rowid,
    name,
    proximity2,
    st_astext(st_transform(geometry,4326)) as pt, 
    st_buffer(geometry, proximity2) as geometry
from 
    "samples" 
order by 
    proximity2 desc 
limit 1;
```